# Access GitLab CI docker container for testing purpose

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am currently trying to deploy an application using GitLab CI and docker.
Spoiler : My pipeline fails everytime so I went a bit into it but I do not understand everything that's happening.

My gitlab runner is a Google Cloud Platform instance. This instance runs the GitLabCI file that call docker builds (so far so good ?). One of the docker build fails for a python/gensim version incompatibility problem.

What I don't understand :
This is my GitLab CI :

```
image: "ubuntu:bionic"

default:
  before_script:
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
    - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
    - apt-key fingerprint *KEY*
    - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

api:
  script:
    - "pwd"
    - "cp scraping/src/variables.env /srv/variables.env"
    - "cp scraping/src/crontab /etc/crontab"
    - "cat /etc/crontab"
    - "docker build -t app-api api/"
    - "docker rm -f app-api || :"
    - "docker run --restart always -d --env-file=/srv/variables.env --name app-api app-api"
    - "docker ps"
```

As you can see, the runner starts by printing his current working directory and copying some files.
Problem is : When I access to the GCP instance and go into the runner docker container (with `docker exec -ti docker-ID /bin/bash`), the current working directory isn't the same
**builds/username/myapp** is printed in pipeline but **/** is printed whenever I connect with SSH. And I can't manage to find the "builds" directory or any of my app directories/files.
My assumption is that when called, the gitlab runner runs a docker container with my project copied inside. And this container builds the other containers.
Am I right ? If yes, how could I access to this container for testing purpose ?

As you can see, I'm a bit lost about what's happening between GitLabCI runner and dockers container. If someone could explain to me who's calling what from where, that'd be great !

**EDIT :**
config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "gcp"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = *TOKEN*
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:latest"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache","/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock","/srv:/srv","/var/spool/cron/crontabs/:/crons"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Comment: This depends on how your runner and your jobs are configured. Can you share relevant parts of your runner's TOML configuration file? There's also the [interactive web terminal](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/interactive_web_terminal/) feature.

Comment: I edited with the TOML config file. I am going to seek into the interactive web terminal, thanks